# Simple view of complex UML class graph

Tags: class, view, uml

We have a complex class model of clinical information. It's intended to support model-driven architecture, so the we can't just defer the complexity. But we also need subject matter experts to be able to review it. Is there a way in UML to create "views" like you would in SQL?
[image]

Comment: Hmm. Posted too fast; can't edit image meta. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

In a diagram, you show only classes you want and you get several diagrams to present all points you need.

Your UML model contains all classes, but in a diagram you present only classes you want.

There i a specific UML meta-class for your purpose : Model which inherits from Package.

"A Model is a description of a system, where ‘system’ is meant in the broadest sense and may include not only software and hardware but organizations and processes. It describes the system from a certain viewpoint (or vantage point) for a certain category of stakeholders (e.g., designers, users, or customers of the system) and at a certain level of abstraction. A Model is complete in the sense that it covers the whole system, although only those aspects relevant to its purpose (i.e., within the given level of abstraction and viewpoint) are represented in the Model." p 245

And

" A model captures a view of a physical system. It is an abstraction of the physical system, with a certain purpose. This purpose determines what is to be included in the model and what is irrelevant. Thus the model completely describes those aspects of the physical system that are relevant to the purpose of the model, at the appropriate level of detail." p 273

And it shown like : 
[image: Model display]

But to do like view, meaning to present to user a "public" view of a complex model, you have to use some patterns like :

- [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)
- [mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)

Comment: Facade looks  like what we want. We're already using packaging to segment the content, but we still need a way to show analysts & SMEs what's going on without getting them bogged down in all the properties to support various implementation patterns. But so far it looks like Facade means documenting everything twice. EA doesn't offer a widget for deriving a facade from existing classes; RSA is all about service facades.

Comment: @ockham I do not know RSA and here it is not allowed to speak about tool, but i understood that RSA provides all needed tools to define facade. It's seem that you get your answer ? If yes i am happy